# Typescript: Extending classes and inheriting types

Tags: typescript, class

I'm working with Classes and Typescript for the first time and I'm having trouble understanding **how** to assign types to my class and more importantly how to tell Classes that extend it what the types its inheriting are.

Consider this class:

```
interface ClassInterface {
  property: string; 
  method(): string;
}

export default class MyClass implements ClassInterface {
  property: string;
  
  constructor(value: string) {
    this.property = string;
  }

  method():string {
    return this.property;
  }
}
```

Right off the bat I'm confused, as everything I've found is telling me I need to have both an interface and I also need to define types within the class itself. Is this the right way to do it? Seems kind of counter intuitive.

I then have another class that extends my first one:

```
export default class ExtendedClass extends MyClass {}
```

What's the best way for me to tell Typescript that `ExtendedClass` has all the same types as `MyClass`? And how would I make that recursive so that if I have another class that extends `ExtendedClass` it can automatically inherit all types from both `MyClass` and `ExtendedClass`?

I've read the Typescript documentation but I couldn't find an answer to any of these questions, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#class-heritage this. you are trying to implement an interface, so your classes have a guideline to implement what the interface has and not missout on any critical piece. 

then the second part would be Inheritance, class does extend all the features of its parents. read here https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#constructors

Comment: So as long as I extend original class all the types will be passed down without me doing anything else?

Comment: Yes, and also there are more things you can do with the inheritance such and overloading and overriding, and more. to leverage some really powerful features of the TS library.

Comment: I'm noticing if I override the constructor on an extended class, the types don't seem to work. Is that intended?

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#super-calls , you have to call super